# D-language: How to print Unicode characters to the console?

Tags: unicode, d

I have the following simple program to generate a random Unicode string from the union of 3 unicode character-sets.

```
#!/usr/bin/env rdmd
import std.uni;
import std.random : randomSample;
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;

/**
*  Random salt generator
*/
dstring get_salt(uint s)
{
    auto unicodechars = unicode("Cyrillic") | unicode("Armenian") | unicode("Telugu");
    dstring unichars =  to!dstring(unicodechars);

    return to!dstring(randomSample(unichars, s));
}

void main()
{
    writeln("Random salt:");
    writeln(get_salt(32));
}
```

However, the output of the writeln is:

```
$ ./teste.d
Random salt:
rw13  13437 78580112 104 3914645
```

What are these numbers? Unicode code-points? How do I print the actual characters? I am on Ubuntu Linux with Locale set to UTF-8

Comment: That `unicodechars` is wrong in a lot of ways. You are bitwise oring those things and idk why that even compiles. You probably want to use `~` concatenation or something instead.

Comment: Care to give a short example? BTW these bitwise ors came from Dlang tutorial on onicode...

Comment: I have no idea how this thing is supposed to work. I have never used this part of the lib before and the docs don't explain it well... what's the link you're reading? But the string you are randomizing right now is just a struct member printing, not a list of chars.

Comment: https://dlang.org/phobos/std_uni.html

Comment: oh i see, it doesn't return a string at all, it returns a magic set object... ok i get it now writing up an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is the problem you have:

```
dstring unichars =  to!dstring(unicodechars);
```

It converts the `CodepointSet` object `unicode` returns to string, not the characters it covers. The set has a name and boundaries of characters but not characters itself. It took this:

```
InversionList!(GcPolicy)(CowArray!(GcPolicy)([1024, 1157, 1159, 1320, 1329, 1367, 1369, 1376, 1377, 1416, 1418, 1419, 1423, 1424, 3073, 3076, 3077, 3085, 3086, 3089, 3090, 3113, 3114, 3124, 3125, 3130, 3133, 3141, 3142, 3145, 3146, 3150, 3157, 3159, 3160, 3162, 3168, 3172, 3174, 3184, 3192, 3200, 7467, 7468, 7544, 7545, 11744, 11776, 42560, 42648, 42655, 42656, 64275, 64280, 5]))
```

And pulled random chars out of that string! Instead, you want:

```
dstring unichars =  to!dstring(unicodechars.byCodepoint);
```

Calling the `byCodepoint` method on that object will yield the actual characters (well, code points, unicode is messy) inside the range, then you get a string out of that and randomize it.

Comment: Excellent Adam! It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot!